# pgAdmin III Restore PLAIN Backup

Tags: postgresql

New to PostgreSQL database, I found column names were automatically converted to lowercase. I created a PLAIN backup, manually edited the column names to proper case. When I tried to restore the edited PLAIN backup, the OK button of pgAdmin3 Restore was disabled.

Is there a way run the edited plain backup file? Please help.

Comment: "failed with errors" - example?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the client program [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) to restore, works fine. The installers of pgAdmin and PostgreSQL also install psql, so you should have it on your pc or your database server.

```
psql -f backup.sql postgres
```

Comment: Where should I place backup.sql, in which directory? I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Just place in C:\ and tell psql where to find it: psql -f "c:/backup.sql" postgres

Comment: you can add -U USERNAME to use this command with other user instead of the default.

Comment: You can also run the following command `\i <path>` on the PSQL prompt.